# Where can I find the history of Windows updates that Microsoft has pushed?

Tags: windows-update, history

My searches for update history seem to only give me hits on articles about the updates on my machine.  That's not what I'm looking for, I want to know when Microsoft made a particular patch or SP available through Windows update.

Does Microsoft provide a history of the Windows updates it has released somewhere on their website?

Comment: Are you looking for a complete history? Or your machine's history? Also, what OS?

Comment: I am looking for a complete history for all versions of Windows.  Well, at least all the currently supported versions.  I figured MS would probably document that somewhere, but I may be hoping for too much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fear the answer is: there isn't any.

I don't think there is a single site giving you that history, every patch or update get's a Knowledge base article which you can search through if you know the content or the number. There have been so many updates in the life cycle of for instance Windows XP that it would be rather inefficient to make a normal indexed list out of it...

You should look on [Microsoft support](http://support.microsoft.com/) for more info if you know what you are looking for.

Answer (score 2):

At [Microsoft Download Center](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/default.aspx) you can find the [latest releases](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/resultsForCategory.aspx?nr=50&sortOrder=Ascending&sortCriteria=Popularity&stype=ss_pd&sterm=All+Categories).

But if you are after an archive, [this site](http://thehotfixshare.net/board/index.php?autocom=downloads) has what you are looking for; (possibly) all the hotfixes ever released by Microsoft!

Answer (score 1):

You can see the history of Windows Update on you machine via "Review your update history". This will show, among other details, the date of installation on your machine. To see the details of an update, right-click and choose "View details".

Comment: I think you need to re-read my question.

Comment: Sorry, my answer was a bit brief and needed some more info:
"View details" proposes "More information", which brings you to the support page that contains the whole and entire information as divulged by MS. The only date available there is "Last Review", which is hopefully reasonably close to when MS made it available (normally a matter of a few days, in my experience).